# Return value from multi dimensional array with keys from another array

Tags: php, arrays

Basically this is what I have

```
$foo = array(
    'bar' = array(
        'baz' = array(
            5
        )
    ),
);
```

And I have another array that holds the keys

```
$keys = array('bar','baz',0);
```

Is there a way I can get the value of the first array with the keys in the second array? I can probably try to write some recursive function that will end up getting the job done, but I was wondering if there was a neat way of doing this by using array functions ( not very good at those ) or something.. ?

Note: keys may not always be 3.

Comment: There is no other way else but using recursion

Comment: You'd need some sort of `array_reduce` that takes two array parameters and walks through both of them, a task too specialized to make it a built-in function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this, it should work

```
$arr = $foo;
foreach($keys as $key)
{
   $arr = $arr[$key];
}

echo $arr; // 5
```

Comment: And to think that I had started writing recursive functions before I asked the question, Jesus! Thank you. Every time I convince myself that the more complicated I think a problem is, the less it actually is.

Comment: There I was, writing something complex.

Comment: Yes in that case no need to use complicated things like pure recursion

Comment: @Martijn I know that feeling.. :D

Answer (score 0):

This could be what you are looking for. (not 100% sure if this would help)

you can see all the array functions on: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php
  some neat ones that might do the trick:

```
   /function.array-fill-keys.php
   /function.array-fill.php
  /function.array-keys.php
```